# Restrict users from one security group to see list items that created by users of another security group

Tags: list, 2013, permissions, view

Is it possible to create a list view, on which user can items that created only by user from same security group?

A list security bits it's not what I'm looking, because it's will restrict access to list items that created by any other user, but need to restrict access based on users security groups.

Simply, users from 'Managers' cannot see/access/modify list items that created by users of 'R&D Dept.' and users from 'R&D Dept.' cannot see/access/modify that created by 'Managers'. It's only two example group, and on production there are hundred of groups.

Thank you for advice.

Update:
Also, one account, for example, INTRANET\JohnSmith must be able to see all list items for all users groups.
I thought it's can be done by customizing permissions on list with breaking inheritance, but I'm not sure how I can modify list view rendering in true secure way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use item level audiencing to specific groups, but that would be a bit cumbersome to maintain. Audiencing isn't really security though.

If this is truely a situation where people should not see others information, the most straightforward way to do this is with separate lists secured properly.

Comment: I would rather use one list for storing that items, because I need to save this historical data

Answer (score 0):

You will need a workflow that will assign permission to different security groups based on content of the list item. You can make your list accessible to all relevant security groups that need access to the list. And then in your workflow, for each group you want to hide the item, you need to remove all existing permissions to the item.

Comment: That can come with a performance penalty depending on how many items are in the list and how many permissions need to be modified.

Comment: @PirateEric, Did you measure the performance penalty? It is one-step workflow. I guess it also depends on what coirius wants to achieve and he will need to weigh it.

Comment: Not on the workflow itself, but rendering the data for page views

Comment: You might want to share what you found out so @coirius can use that info to decide

Answer (score 0):

You could use a infopath form and usrprofile service to get the users info, and then check that against a separately managed list of groups and show/hide based on access. So anyone could still 'click' on the item, but only the approved could see the data